# divide a matrix into multiple matrices in python at specific locations

Tags: python

I have the following matrix (or 2D list):

```
matrix = [['0','0'],
          ['2','3'],
          ['1','9'],
          ['7','11'], 
          ['1','2'], 
          ['7','23'],
          ['0','0'],
          ['6','8'],
          ['3','1'],
          ['8','1'],
          ['4','3'],
          ['0','0'],
          ['63','9'],
          ['31','10'],
          ['82','11'],
          ['41','31']]
```

I would like to split it into multiple matrices based on the value in the row. The zeros will determine the location of the split:

```
matrix1 = [['0','0'],
           ['2','3'],
           ['1','9'],
           ['7','11'],
           ['1','2'],
           ['7','23']]

matrix2 = [['0','0'],
           ['6','8'],
           ['3','1'],
           ['8','1'],
           ['4','3']]
          
matrix3 = [['0','0'],
           ['63','9'],
           ['31','10'], 
           ['82','11'],
           ['41','31']]
```

Then I need to write them to a CSV file (adjacent to each other) like this:

[image: CSV output]

Comment: share the code you tried

Comment: And could `matrix` NOT start with `['0','0']` ? would it then give you the expected result?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75463356/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

matrix = [['0','0'],
          ['2','3'],
          ['1','9'],
          ['7','11'], 
          ['1','2'], 
          ['7','23'],
          ['0','0'],
          ['6','8'],
          ['3','1'],
          ['8','1'],
          ['4','3'],
          ['0','0'],
          ['63','9'],
          ['31','10'],
          ['82','11'],
          ['41','31']]


zero_pos = [i for i,element in enumerate(matrix) if element == ['0', '0']]
num_mats = len(zero_pos)
matrices = [matrix[zero_pos[i]:zero_pos[i+1]] if i+1<num_mats else matrix[zero_pos[i]:] for i in range(num_mats)]

with open('temp_output.csv', 'w', newline = '') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    

    for row in zip_longest(*matrices):
        writer.writerow([element for matrix in row if matrix is not None for element in matrix])
```